# How to align time series with respect to reference waveform?

Tags: python, time-series, cross-correlation

I have multiple time series data and want to align with respect to the first one using cross-correlation. After the cross-correlation, I have changed the start time of waveform accoring to delay time, but could not align them with reference trace and don’t know where is something wrong. I shared a very brief demo of my code. Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated...

```
ref_tr=obspy.read(refernce[0])    
#do cc and plots

    #---------------station info for cc--------------------- 

for event_file in eve_list:
    
    
    sta_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(event_file,"*ML0*BHZ*"))
    i=0
    for sta_file in sta_files:
        org_tr = obspy.read(sta_file)
         
     #---------------do cross correlation --------------------- 
        
        corr_result = xcorr(org_tr.data,ref_tr.data,10)
        
        corr_result = list(corr_result/(np.linalg.norm(org_tr[0].data)*np.linalg.norm(ref_tr[0].data)))
        
        max_corr = max(corr_result)
        
        max_index = corr_result.index(max_corr)
        
        cc_diff=(max_index-10)*delta                  
    
#      #---------------modify the start time accordingly--------------------- 

        
        org_tr[0].stats.starttime=org_tr[0].stats.starttime+ timedelta(seconds=float(cc_diff))
        
     #---------------plot the waveforms --------------------- 

        data = sta_tr[0].data.copy()

        if max(data) != min(data):

            sta_tr[0].data=data/(max(data) - min(data)) # Normalize data    

            sampling_rate = sta_tr[0].stats.sampling_rate

            plt.plot(np.arange(0,len(sta_tr[0].data))*1/sampling_rate,
                     sta_tr[0].data+dist,
                     color=color,
                    linewidth=0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by aligned. The red and black seem aligned. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I want to align at fixed time with a reference trace so we can further differentiate their pattern.., For example, at time 3s; all of them should be aligned vertically.